# MakeFile: Link a library - mingw

Tags: dll, makefile

I have a C program with a path like this :

- pgrmusinglib.c
- pgrmusinglib.h
- main.c
- libfolder

  - libmylibrary.dll

I am trying to compile it on windows using mingw64.
I built this Makefile

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -O3
DEPS = pgrmusinglib.h 
LDFLAGS =  -L/$(LIB) -lmylibrary
LIB = libfolder


SRC=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)


all: pgrm

pgrm : $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

The pgrm rule fails with error :

```
c:/programdata/chocolatey/lib/mingw/tools/install/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
cannot find -lmylibrary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is'nt working because of how you wrote the LDFLAGS, just a little typo I assume, you put a  '/' in front of the directory name , so its looking for libfolder in your root directory. Try either removing the '/' or putting a period '.' In front of it

Comment: I think it worked removing the /. Thanks. Now i have an  ``undefined reference to `WinMain'`` error

Comment: Add '@' after -o in your pgrm Target

Comment: Right now its using an object file as the out put name, adding '@' after -o would insert your target name 'pgrm' as the output name